# Qt Qsplitter handle drag messes up color and icon

Tags: c++, css, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

In my qt application, I am using a QDock widget which, whenever dragged to change its size, messes up the icon and color on the handle.

My stylesheet for the splitter is:

```
QMainWindow::separator:vertical,
QSplitter::handle:horizontal {
  image: url(icon:/primary/splitter-horizontal.svg);
}
```

same for the horizontal splitter.

[GIF of the issue is here, as it is difficult to describe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMJIS.gif)

Comment: tray  `QSplitter::handle:horizontal {
  image: url(icon:/primary/splitter-horizontal.svg);
}`                      
`QSplitter::handle:pressed {
 image: url(icon:/primary/splitter-horizontal.svg);}`

Comment: no luck, same issue occurs. If there is any way to completely disable them, that would work too, i don't know how to remove the bars in their entirety while still allowing resizing.